# adding Interstitial into chartboost

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, admob, chartboost

so after a week of attempting to load chart boost to my non-arc iOS app in Xcode, I'm gonna start asking some really silly questions.
my code in my appdelegate is:

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];

    cb.appId = @"530dd707f8975c182ae2c691";
    cb.appSignature = @"0d8726e69c911a182b0cefac4eca36f692355725";

    // Required for use of delegate methods. See "Advanced Topics" section below.
    cb.delegate = self;

    // Begin a user session. Must not be dependent on user actions or any prior network requests.
    // Must be called every time your app becomes active.
    [cb startSession];
    [cb showMoreApps];
    [cb cacheInterstitial:@"Play Again"];
    [cb showInterstitial:@"Play Again"];
    // Show an interstitial
    [cb cacheInterstitial:@"Highscores"];
    [cb showInterstitial:@"Highscores"];
```

when i start the app, yea i get the test ad appear so thats all good, but  i cannot get it to show apps throughout the game or get these interstitials working at all.

so my first question: will the random ad's appear throughout the app(but only when the game is uploaded to the app store and not through test mode)

and secondly, can someone please explain with this showInterstitial locations. I've read many many documentations, even looked through the examples on chart boost, which they only link to buttons rather than to, for example, when i die in the game and then i want an ad to appear.
so can someone explain on here how to implement these interstitial appearance, as my "play again" and "highscores" seem to do nothing(and yes I've added a campaign logic but still, no ad is showing when the player dies and the screen goes to the high score page

Answer (score 1):

few things:

1. Ads will appear throughout the app, not at random but where you place them.
2. The locations are simply names for your own reference. You still need to place the `showInterstitial` code in the right place for it to show when you want in. For instance, when your player dies and you should call `[cb showInterstitial:@"play again"];` and when the player navigates to the high score page you call `[cb showInterstitial:@"highscores"];`.

The location names can be anything: `location1`, `location2` or `play again`, `highscores`... it doesn't actually matter. But you should call `[cb showInterstitial:@"play again"];` *only* on play again, and `[cb showInterstitial:@"highscores"];` *only* when players view the high score screen. Once you set all that up in the app, you can turn interstitials on/off via the dashboard.

Finally, you should never call `cacheInterstitial` and `showInterstitial` immediately after each other. This can cause a race condition and produce unexpected results. Simply call `cacheInterstitial` when you bootup, and `showInterstitial` everywhere else in your app.

If you have any other questions, feel free to email support@chartboost.com
*Full disclosure: I work at Chartboost*